# Short handed/Ternary Operator if statment not working, the logic looks correct to me so i need another set of eyes to check it out

Tags: c#, if-statement, while-loop, conditional-operator, shorthand

So what the program I'm creating for my course is pascals triangle and the method takes the apex of the triangle and display's it. The old code that is commented out rn does work and had zero issues, but since i wanna try and always advance my coding skills, i tried to make it cleaner and smaller with short hand if statements, if you see what the issue i am having is id appreciate you letting me know, the sample data for getting the correct apex is
`4,1,7,9,2 = Apex(7)` but with the new code its giving me `6`

```
using System;

namespace Lab4
{
    class Program
    {
        // apex will add each pairs of cards, if over 9 wtvr remaining is thats the new sum
        static int Pyramid(int x, int y)
        {
            x = (x + y > 9) ? (x + y) - 9 : x + y;
            return x;
        }
        static int Apex(int Card1,int Card2,int Card3,int Card4,int Card5)
        {
            int x = 0;
            int cycle = 0;
            while (cycle < 5 ) // tells it how many cycles it needs to get to the apex
            {
                
                //having a cycle counter allows the if statment to know when to cancel the last card out ,from 5-2
       
                Card1 = (cycle == 5) ? Card1     : Pyramid(Card1, Card2);
                Card2 = (cycle == 4) ? 0 : Pyramid(Card2, Card3);
                Card3 = (cycle == 3) ? 0 : Pyramid(Card3, Card4);
                Card4 = (cycle == 2) ? 0 : Pyramid(Card4, Card5);
                Card5 = 0;
               
                cycle++;
                
            }
            x = Card1;
            return x;
        }
        static int PickCard() //method is used to let user input card and check to see if card is a correct input 1-9
        {
           int x=int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); //allows user to input their card choice
            while (x < 1 || x > 9)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please Only Choose Cards From 1-9");
                x = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Please Choose Next Card"); // tells user to choose next card, works since its after the while loop verifies their og input
            return x;
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int ApexCard;
            int Card1,Card2,Card3, Card4, Card5;
            Console.WriteLine("Please Choose 5 Cards Going Left To Right From 1-9");
            Card1 = PickCard();
            Card2 = PickCard();
            Card3 = PickCard();
            Card4 = PickCard();
            Card5 = PickCard();
            ApexCard = Apex(Card1, Card2, Card3, Card4, Card5);
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine($"Your Apex Card is {ApexCard}");
        //Author Jonaven Gray 06/21
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ternary Operator

Comment: Can you clearly separate out both versions of the code, maybe extract them each into their own method ApexWorking(..) and ApexNotWorking(..).

Answer (score 0):

You have incorrect apex calculations using current logic.

Your old logic is (commented and working):

```
static int Apex(int Card1,int Card2,int Card3,int Card4,int Card5)
{
    int x = 0;
    int cycle = 0;
    while (cycle < 5 )
    {
        Card1 = Pyramid(Card1, Card2);
        Card2 = Pyramid(Card2, Card3);
        Card3 = Pyramid(Card3, Card4);
        Card4 = Pyramid(Card4, Card5);
        Card5 = (cycle == 1) ? Card5 = 0 : Card5=0;
        
        cycle++;
        
        if (cycle==1) 
        {            
            Card5 = 0;
        }
        else if (cycle == 2)
        {
            Card4 = 0;
        }
        else if (cycle == 3)
        {
            Card3 = 0;
        }
        else if (cycle == 4)
        {
            Card2 = 0;
        }
        else if (cycle == 5)
        {
            x=Card1;
        }
    }
    x = Card1;
    return x;
}
```

So you call `Pyramid` method for cards and then "reset" cards to `0`.

Your current code does different thing - you firstly check `cycle` and then call `Pyramid` if condition is met (note that in previous version you call `Pyramid` always). So you `Apex` method should be like this:

```
static int Apex(int Card1,int Card2,int Card3,int Card4,int Card5)
{
    int x = 0;
    int cycle = 0;
    while (cycle < 5 )
    {
        Card1 = Pyramid(Card1, Card2);
        Card2 = Pyramid(Card2, Card3);
        Card3 = Pyramid(Card3, Card4);
        Card4 = Pyramid(Card4, Card5);          
        
        cycle++;
        
        Card2 = (cycle == 4) ? 0 : Card2;
        Card3 = (cycle == 3) ? 0 : Card3;
        Card4 = (cycle == 2) ? 0 : Card4;
        Card5 = (cycle == 1) ? 0 : Card5;
    }
    x = Card1;
    return x;
}
```

The `Pyramid` method is correct (both `ternary` and `if-else` versions).

Comment: is there a way to condense that into one line with the pyramid? because after the cycle goes through those numbers arent needed anymore

Comment: @JGray, why do you need it to be one line? Shorter does not mean better. Code should be readable and simple. Maybe you can refactor `Apex` method somehow to be one line but I don't see the point of doing this and don't think you can do this without overhead.

Comment: i just wanted to try and make it shorter, i thought it was easier to read that way, still doesnt make sense y it woulndt work but can ask my instructor about it

Comment: Readable, understandable and maintainable beat shorter every time